# Autowiring authentication in LocaleChangeInterceptor to store lang in DB not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to store the user's lang in the database. Therefore I extended the LocaleChangeInterceptor and compare the old with the new locale setting.

If changed, I want to update the user attribute in the DB. But the authentication object gets not autowired.

Any ideas?

```
public class CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor extends LocaleChangeInterceptor {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    Authentication authentication;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    private String oldLanguage;


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
    throws ServletException {
        oldLanguage = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().toString();
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        String newLanguage = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().toString();

        // stores new user language if changed
        if (authentication != null && oldLanguage != newLanguage) {
            CurrentUser currentUser = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            User user = userService.getUserById(currentUser.getUser().getId());
            user.setLang(newLanguage);
            userService.save(user);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It will not get autowired as it isn't a spring managed bean. Also your code is flawed... Imagine 10 concurrent requests all setting the instance level variable `oldLanguage`... Which language do you think the first request eventually sees/compares?

Comment: You're right, this won't work. But how can I update the user language in the DB once it is changed? I dont want to run an update query on every request.

Comment: See the answer which gives you the solution how you should retrieve the current user. (Or just use `request.getPrincipal`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the `Authentication` is managed by spring, So could you try to use following code to get `Authentication`.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```